# How do you return the last letter in a string of text in an adjacent column?

Tags: worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007

Rather than do 600+ entries manually before seeing if some superuser might be able to answer my question, I'm going straight to "the Oracle" first this time.  By the way, @Scott Craner answered my question perfectly last time, so I am hoping he or someone else will be able to answer this one as well.

What I need to do now is return the last letter of a string of text in an adjacent column.  It sounds simple enough, and I have tried looking this up online, but haven't seen exactly what I'm looking for yet.  I'll continue to look, but I have a feeling some superuser knows exactly how to do this.  Below is an image of what it is I want to do:

[image]

As you can see, I did the first 10 by hand, to give you a visual.  I entered the letters in caps, but this is not necessary.  If it is easier to do this using the format (lower case) of the originating text, that's perfectly fine.

I am using Excel 2007 and appreciate the expertise of anyone who can help me answer this.

And as always, if this has already been answered in some other thread, please let me know.  I did make an attempt to see if someone may have already asked such a question, but don't see anything that addresses exactly what I am looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the formula `=RIGHT(A2,1)` will do what you want. If there might be a space at the end of the text, you could use `=RIGHT(TRIM(A2,1))` to ignore the space.

[image: Click here for a picture of what I mean]

If you want something even more understandable, format your data as a table. Select all your data, go to Home→Styles→Format As Table, and make sure the "My Table has Headers" checkbox is selected. Then in the "Endings" column you can simply use the formula `=RIGHT(TRIM([@Noun]),1)` which will then be automatically copied to the entire table and is IMO more immediately understandable.

You can read more about the cool uses of tables at https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Using-structured-references-with-Excel-tables-F5ED2452-2337-4F71-BED3-C8AE6D2B276E.

Comment: Thanks for providing such a quick answer @Micah Lindström!  I'm going to test it out now to see if this works out.  In the meantime, thanks for providing a visual ... very helpful.

Comment: Worked like a charm, @Micah Lindström.  Thank you very much, indeed, and thank you also for the link to expand my knowledge of all the cool things you can do with Microsoft Excel.  You're awesome.

Comment: Thanks @fixer1234, it's too bad there's not just a script that can handle that conversion for images from new users.

Comment: You're off to a good start.  Here an hour and already three good answers, all upvoted, one accepted.  I think you probably have enough rep already to access image posting.